# Enable Auto Accept for User End when MS Teams Meeting Invite or Call Is initiated by a Teams App (Bot)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-teams

A MS Teams App (Bot) built using the Bot Framework and MS Graph.  Bot answers a call and wishes to
A. Directly as a one-to-one call to a Teams User or
B. transfer the call to a Teams Meeting.

We have coded these and these implementations work.

The app is intended to be used in a contact center type environment.  So before the bot transfers the incoming call, it identifies the target user to whom the call should be transferred (Scenario A above).    The second implementation is where the call is transferred to a Teams Meeting, and the target user is invited to that Meeting by the bot (Scenario B)

What we are looking for is a Graph Call, a Client Side API, or possibly a  Teams Policy, or any other approach  where the target user Teams Client will auto accept the call (Scenario A) or the Teams Meeting Invite (Scenario B) as long as it is sent by our Teams App (bot).

The feature is intended to avoid the two-accept situation where the target user (1) first indicates that they are available to engage  and then (2) again accept the call or Teams Invite from the bot. The goal is that if the target user has designated themselves as free or available that the call or Teams Invite would get accepted as soon as sent.

Additionally, we are looking for decline events when the target user  declines the call.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

(There appears to be an auto accept Policy but seems limited to Teams Room Devices)